# lxml: How do I search for fields without adding a xmlns (localhost) path to each search term?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml

I'm trying to locate fields in a SOAP xml file using lxml (3.6.0)

```
...
<soap:Body>
<Request xmlns="http://localhost/">
<Test>
<field1>hello</field1>
<field2>world</field2>
</Test>
</Request>
</soap:Body>
...
```

In this example I'm trying to find `field1` and `field2`.

I need to add a path to the search term, to find the field:

```
print (myroot.find(".//{http://localhost/}field1").tag) # prints 'field1'
```

without it, I don't find anything

```
print (myroot.find("field1").tag) # finds 'None'
```

Is there any other way to search for the field tag (here `field1`) without giving path info?

Full example below:

```
from lxml import etree

example = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body><Request xmlns="http://localhost/">
<Test><field1>hello</field1><field2>world</field2></Test>
</Request></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
"""
myroot = etree.fromstring(example)

# this works
print (myroot.find(".//{http://localhost/}field1").text)
print (myroot.find(".//{http://localhost/}field2").text)

# this fails
print (myroot.find(".//field1").text)
print (myroot.find("field1").text)
```

Comment: The input of the SOAP request is given, I can't change any of it in real live to make things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to ignore namespace when selecting element using XPath, but that isn't a good practice. Namespace is there for a reason. Anyway, there is a cleaner way to reference element in namespace i.e by using namespace prefix that was mapped to the namespace uri, instead of using the actual namespace uri every time :

```
.....
>>> ns = {'d': 'http://localhost/'}
>>> print (myroot.find(".//d:field1", ns).text)
hello
>>> print (myroot.find(".//d:field2", ns).text)
world
```

Comment: This is slightly nicer, but still requires me to reference  `http://localhost/` in code. Is there a safe way to query the `myroot` for the namespace used so that the code could locate the fields if the namespace is different?

(Explanation: In the real world I'm parsing a log full of requests sent to a .net service and not all requests have `http://localhost/` references.)

Comment: The problem is, the default namespace in your XML is not declared at the root element level, so it isn't directly available in `myroot`. Will the element where `xmlns=".."` declared is always named `Request`?

Comment: I'm not sure, yet. I have differents parties calling a .net service and their calling behavior is not consistent. I found some that also declare an xmlsn at root level and give this a name that is repeated in further fields... Like `<name:field1>hello</name:field1>`

Comment: Looks like ignoring namespace would be a much easier way to go at this point, since you consider handling not only default namespace but also prefixed namespace like `name:` you mentioned... : `myroot.xpath("//*[local-name()='field1']")[0].text`